# semaphore is accessing same data structure

Tags: multithreading, semaphore

I would like to understand the semaphore better. A semaphore allows X number of threads (let us say 10 thread are accessing same thread function) to enter to specific thread function, so what will happen if all 10 threads are trying to access same data structure in same time. Do we need any additional lock mechanism required to avoid this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a semaphore:

```
val s: Semaphore(1)
```

which defines a semaphore with an initial count of 1.

Then accessing a function is done by:

```
s.await()
invoke_function()
s.notify()
```

If you have 10 threads, then each thread would perform `await()` on the semaphore, but only one thread at a time could proceed. The operation of the semaphore ensures that only one thread can do `invoke_function()` at a time.

Finally, the `notify()` on the semaphore releases the resource and allows another thread to access the function.

The area between the `await()` and `notify()` is often called a **critical section**. The semaphore itself provides locking of access to the data structure.

However, this model of thread control skips over a number of issues surrounding the underlying memory model.

Answer (score 0):

For the part of your question - what happens when two threads try to acquire an atomic resource at exactly the **same time**. The answer is - ***it does not happen exactly at same time.***

These atomic operations need support at hardware level. In the case of multiple threads/processes there will always be one who acquires a hardware lock and uses atomic instruction (like `LOCK` and `CMPXCHG` on Intel architecture) before another thread/process does that.